# SocketIO C++ emitting and receiving messages

Tags: c++, socket.io

My last question on the subject wasn't written well, I hope to be more specific with this question.
edit: the github library i reference is :https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

I am trying to build a C++ socketIO client that will send and receive messages from a node JS server.
I cant seem to be able to receive messages well like the message contents, only the message name.
my basic code:

```
void button(sio::event &ev)
{
    cout<<"got button"<<endl;
    const sio::message::ptr& message_received = ev.get_message();
    cout<< message_received <<endl;

}

int main(int argc ,const char* args[]{
sio::client h;
connection_listener l(h);

h.set_open_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_connected, &l));
h.set_close_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_close, &l,std::placeholders::_1));
h.set_fail_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_fail, &l));
h.set_logs_verbose();
h.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
current_socket = h.socket();


string color="green";
current_socket->emit("color", color;
current_socket->on("button_hold", &button); 

current_socket->on("button_hold", [&](sio::event& ev){
    cout<<"button press"<<endl;
    const sio::message::ptr& message_received = ev.get_message();
    cout<< message_received <<endl; 

});
```

message_received returns the address of the message and not the message itself, and i cant seem to get the message in any way i try.

on the node side i get:

```
io.emit("button_hold","1")
io.emit("button_hold","0")
```

or sometimes i send a struct on node, but the syntax is the same,
i want to receive that "1" or "0" or anything else that the server sends.

when printing message_received i get:

```
got button
0x7fa8006e60
got button
0x7fa8009780
```

in socketio documentation i couldn't find a solution and i hope i can get help here.

Comment: Have you tried dereferencing the pointer or calling a method on it? I’m not sure what a sio::message::ptr is offhand but it’s likely you need to do one of the two above options.

Comment: @Taekahn the example they give is something like this:
current_socket->on("new message", sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](string const& name, message::ptr const& data, bool isAck,message::list &ack_resp)
                       {
                           _lock.lock();
                           string user = data->get_map()["username"]->get_string();
                           string message = data->get_map()["message"]->get_string();
                           EM(user<<":"<<message); }));

but my message is simple without a struct, no use for get_map()

Answer (score 1):

OK so after playing around with my messages for a while i managed to receive a basic message like this:

```
current_socket->on("button_hold", sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](string const& name, message::ptr const& data, bool isAck,message::list &ack_resp)
            {
                _lock.lock();
                cout<<"got button press"<<endl;
                cout<<data->get_string()<<endl;
                _lock.unlock();
            }));
```

because i don't have mapping in my messages and only a basic message name and contents i can simply use get_string() or get_int() to receive most message types.
Now i will be working on more advance message building with structs or JSON.
Socketio library has much to offer and it will take some time to master so any suggestions are welcomed